# Optimizing random access read and random access write in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I'd like to optimize the random access read, and random access write in the following code:

```
__global__ void kernel(float* input, float* output, float* table, size_t size)
{
int x_id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
if (x_id > size)
    return;

float in_f = input[x_id];
int in_i = (int)(floor(in_f));
int table_index = (int)((in_f - float(in_i)) * 1024000.0f );
float* t = table + table_index;
output[table_index] = t[0] * in_f;

}
```

As you can see, the index to the table and to the output are determined at run-time, and completely random.

I understand that I can use texture memory or `__ldg()` for reading such data.
So, my questions are:

1. Is there better way to read a randomly indexed data than using the texture memory or `__ldg()`?
2. What about the random access write as the case of `output[table_index]` above?

Actually, I'm adding the code here to give an example of random access read and write. I do not need code optimization, I just need a high level description of the best way to deal with such situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no magic bullets for random access of data on the GPU.

The best advice is to attempt to perform data reorganization or some other method to regularize the data access.  For repeated/heavy access patterns, even such intensive methods as sorting operations on the data may result in an overall net improvement in performance.

Since your question implies that the random access is unavoidable, the main thing you can do is intelligently make use of caches.

The L2 is a device-wide cache, and all DRAM accesses go through it.  So thrashing of the L2 may be unavoidable if you have large-scale random accesses.  There aren't any functions to disable (selectively or otherwise) the L2 for either read or write accesses (*).

For smaller scale cases, the main thing you can do is route the accesses through one of the "non-L1" caches, i.e. the [texture cache](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-functions) (on all GPUs) and [the Read-Only cache](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ldg-function) (i.e. `__ldg()`) on cc3.5 and higher GPUs.  The use of these caches may help in 2 ways:

1. For some access patterns that would thrash the linear-organized L1, you may get some cache hits in the texture or read-only cache, due to a different caching strategy employed by those caches.
2. On devices that also have an L1 cache in use, routing the "random" traffic through an alternate cache will keep the L1 "unpolluted" and therefore less likely to thrash. In other words, the L1 may still provide caching benefit for other accesses, since it is not being thrashed by the random accesses.

Note that the compiler may route traffic through the read-only cache for you, without explicit use of `__ldg()`, if you decorate appropriate pointers with `const  __restrict__` as described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0)

You can also use [cache control hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62664165/cuda-error-identifier-stcs-is-undefined) on loads and stores.

Similar to the above advice for protecting the L1, it may make sense on some devices, in some cases to perform loads and stores in an "uncached" fashion.  You can generally get the compiler to handle this for you through the use of the `volatile` [keyword](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#volatile-qualifier).  You can keep both an ordinary and a `volatile` pointer to the same data, so that accesses that you can regularize can use the "ordinary" pointer, and "random" accesses can use the `volatile` version.  Other mechanisms to pursue uncached access would be to use the [ptxas compiler switches](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#ptxas-options) (e.g. `-Xptxas dlcm=cg`) or else manage the load/store operations via appropriate use of [inline PTX](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html#abstract) with appropriate [caching modifiers](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#data-movement-and-conversion-instructions).

The "uncached" advice is the main advice I can offer for "random" writes.  Use of the [surface mechanism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#surface-functions) might provide some benefit for some access patterns, but I think it is unlikely to make any improvement for random patterns.

(*) This has changed in recent versions of CUDA and for recent GPU families such as Ampere (cc 8.x).  There is a new capability to reserve a portion of the L2 for [data persistence](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#L2_access_intro).  Also see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#L2-cache)

Comment: What about saving table_indexes in another array and in second kernel, each thread searches for its table_index and when all threads in a smx finds their indexes, after a synchronization, all those threads write to their  own memory point. Would this synchronized(also contiguous / linear) writes give more performance than it takes(for searching(reading(probably from cache)))?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik   I don't really understand exactly what you are proposing.  It's not obvious to me that what you are proposing would result in contiguous or efficient access patterns.   In any event, if you have a specific case that you would like to describe, you may want to pose a new question.  Feel free to link back to this question for context if that helps.

Comment: I meant packing consecutive(i,i+1,i+2,i+3) writes together before writing. Is fetching indexes, feasible for this?