# CUDA error identifier "__stcs" is undefined

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

I want to use *store function with cache hint* `__stcs` on GPU Pascal, CUDA 10.0.

In [CUDA C++ Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#stx-functions) there is no mention of any header for data type `unsigned long long`, but the compiler return an error `identifier "__stcs" is undefined`.

How to fix this compilation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These intrinsics require CUDA 11.0, they are new for CUDA 11.0.

If you look at the [CUDA 10.0 programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.0/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html)  you will see they are not mentioned.   You can also see that they are mentioned in the "changes from Version 10.2" section of [the 11.0 programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#changes-from-previous-version).

You also need to compile for compute capability 3.5 or higher.